# how to corrrectly work with auto layout programmatically in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i have tried to place  UILabels and the image view in a custom table view cell

```
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
 {
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    _Header = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(94, 10, 206, 21)];
    _Subtitle =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(94, 30, 206, 21)];
    _CommentLabel =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 71, 100, 17)];
    _TimeLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(94, 71, 75, 17)];
    _Post_IMAGE = [[CHTVC_ImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9, 7, 77, 81)];

    self.Header.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    self.Header.numberOfLines = 0;
    //self.Header.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    self.Subtitle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    self.Subtitle.numberOfLines = 0;
    //self.Subtitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;


      //self.CommentLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
      //self.TimeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
      //self.Post_IMAGE.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;


            //adding the subviews
    [self.contentView addSubview:_Header];
    [self.contentView addSubview:_Subtitle];
    [self.contentView addSubview:_CommentLabel];
    [self.contentView addSubview:_TimeLabel];
    [self.contentView addSubview:_Post_IMAGE];
    }
```

but after writing the following lines of code for adding the constraints :

```
    NSArray * CELLconstraints = @[[NSLayoutConstraint  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[Post_IMAGE]-8-[Header]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"Post_IMAGE":self.Post_IMAGE,@"Header":self.Header}],
                              [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[Header]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"Header": self.Header}],
                              [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[Post_IMAGE]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"Post_IMAGE": self.Post_IMAGE}],
                              [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[Post_IMAGE]-8-[Subtitle]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"Post_IMAGE": self.Post_IMAGE,@"Subtitle":self.Subtitle}],
                              [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[Subtitle]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"Subtitle":self.Subtitle}],
                              [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[Post_IMAGE(100@20)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"Post_IMAGE": self.Post_IMAGE}],
                              [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[Post_IMAGE(100@20)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"Post_IMAGE": self.Post_IMAGE}],
                              [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-200-[CommentLabel]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"CommentLabel": self.CommentLabel}],
                              [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[CommentLabel]-8-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"CommentLabel": self.CommentLabel}],
                              [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-94-[TimeLabel]-151-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"TimeLabel": self.TimeLabel}],
                              [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[TimeLabel]-8-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"TimeLabel": self.TimeLabel}]];
    for (NSLayoutConstraint * constraints in CELLconstraints) {
        [self.contentView addConstraints:constraints];
    };
```

my custom cell subviews are not properly positioned......plus I'm getting constraint errors.... as they are mentioned in my console

anyways i know that i don't know how  to place the views correctly  using auto layout .........can someone help me please

please note that the uilabels and the cell are ment to be dynamic in size

Comment: Please post console output as it tells you what and where it's going wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason that all of the lines that turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` are commented out?

Comment: As Ken is suggesting, not turning off translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is a bad idea. That guarantees  conflicts between the auto resizing mask based constraints and the ones you creating. Don't do that.

Comment: You also shouldn't be setting the fames of the views you'r creating. Just use "alloc init", or "new" to create them. All sizing and positioning should be done with the constraints.

Comment: @KenThomases thank you for noting that  i commented my `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints `. when i removed all the comment syntaxes ....... i stopped getting errors in my console. however the subviews in my custom cell contentView are still positioned wrongly...........i need help please

Comment: You will need to show how they are positioned incorrectly compared to what you expected.